# Help on SEDE query for count of the deleted answers for given user

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to get count of the deleted answers for given user. I have written this SEDE query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/revision/886198/1099709/count-of-the-answers-deleted-for-user

This outputs 0 with my user id as parameter which is wrong.

Can someone please help me to correct this query?

Comment: SEDE does not track deleted posts.  So 0 is the correct result.

Comment: SEDE including deleted posts would kind of defeat the purpose of the [view deleted posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @Justastudent: I do not want to "view" the deleted post. I just want its count.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Deleted posts in SEDE are available, but anonymized. This means you can't view the count of deleted answers for a specific user.

Deleted posts also get removed from related tables like PostHistory to avoid people working around the anonymization.

Comment: Is there a way to delete that SEDE query? That query looks useless now. Others may get confused.

Comment: Not as far as I know. I don't think SEDE offers the possibility of deleting queries at all. You can add a comment saying this doesn't work, though, if you still have it open.

Comment: Is there a way to know how many (my own) questions and/or answers I have deleted so far?

Comment: Not unless you get >10K rep or find a willing mod, as far as I know. You can search with [user:me deleted:true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Atrue), but afaik that's only the last 2 months for users with less than 10K rep (user:me is strictly not even needed because you can only search your own deleted posts).

Comment: (Possibly, you can get all your data by submitting a GDPR data request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). This should include all your deleted posts, afaik, but I haven't tried)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That also gives me my posts that aren't deleted: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4733879+deleted%3Atrue So this feature seems kinda broken for <10K rep users.

Comment: @Filnor Yes, sorry. This apparently doesn't work at all for <10K rep users. You can use the deleted recent questions and deleted recent answers links on your profile instead. The links are https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/userid and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/userid where you have to fill in your userid of course.